# Simple question about HS algorithm's formul(Optical flow)

Tags: algorithm, math

In the below pic, I can not understand what `U` vector is? It says `flow field` but I can not imagie what really is the flow field?

[image]

Comment: You should ask this question in Signalprocessing.se for a faster and probably better answer